# Adding toprule and bottomrule to the glossary

Tags: glossaries, rules, glossaries-extra, vskip

I figured out how to add the toprule to this glossary, but I failed to do the same for the bottomrule. So, for this MWE, I have two questions:

1. How can I add a bottomrule at the end of the glossary?
2. How to control the vertical skip between the toprule and bottomrule, and the first and last entries, respectively?,

finding that `\toprule\\[-\baselineskip]` has no effect at all as if it is written `\toprule\\[0em]`, which needs some explanation why `\\[-\baselineskip]` is not fetched as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage[stylemods]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth
\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{nameunitdesc}{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-6\tabcolsep}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule\\[-\baselineskip]% it strangely has the same effect of \\[0em]
 }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{L}{name={L},description={some text},symbol={---}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name={Cp},description={specific heat}, symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\begin{document}

\gls{L}, \gls{P}.

\glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol{\glsunitwidth}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{\glsgetwidestname}
\ifdim\dimen0>\glsnamewidth
    \glsnamewidth=\dimen0
\fi

\printnoidxglossary[style=nameunitdesc,sort=use]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the lines inside of the definition of `{theglossary}`:

```
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular} {@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}\toprule}%
    {\bottomrule\end{supertabular}}%
```

With `\\[-\baselineskip]` you experience normal LaTeX table behaviour: A negative argument is effictively ignored here because the optional argument would be implemented as a line with negative depth, but during box packaging TeX sets the depth of a hbox to at least zero.
You can avoid this problem by controlling spacing using the `booktabs` command `\addlinespace` instead of having to insert a line and going back with `-\baselineskip`.
In the example I used it to add 5pt of vertical space below the top line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage[stylemods]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth
\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{nameunitdesc}{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-6\tabcolsep}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}\toprule\addlinespace[5pt]}%
    {\bottomrule\end{supertabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\glsnoexpandfields

\newglossaryentry{L}{name={L},description={some text},symbol={---}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name={Cp},description={specific heat}, symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\begin{document}

\gls{L}, \gls{P}.

\glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol{\glsunitwidth}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{\glsgetwidestname}
\ifdim\dimen0>\glsnamewidth
    \glsnamewidth=\dimen0
\fi

\printnoidxglossary[style=nameunitdesc,sort=use]

\end{document}
```

[image]